# How to get recently opened application name in android?

Tags: android

In my application i want to get the opened application name in my application

I tried some code but all of them retrieving only running application but I need only the application that i opened i.e If i opened facebook application means i want only that name

How to do this

Comment: when you say "you opened", who is "you" in this? You're interested in which applications your application has opened? Or which applications the user has opened?

Comment: The applications which the user opened

Answer (score 0):

There's very little difference between "open" applications and "running" applications. If you want the currently visible application, that's almost certainly not possible as it would be a huge security hole.